# Workflow Criteria evaluates to true but object not added to time based workflow

Tags: workflow, field-update, time-dependent-workflow

I have created a time-based workflow that checks some criteria on a custom objects and adds them to a time-based queue to execute 60 days after a particular date on the object. When we edit and save the object and then review the debug logs. They clearly state the the criteria for the workflow rule that executes the time trigger was met and evaluated to true but the record was not added to the time-based workflow queue of records.

When viewing all the records under this time trigger none of the records that I know passed the workflow have been added. Is there some step or process that I am missing as to how this works? It seems that if I leave it alone for a few days eventually some records will trickle into this list but never if I view it right after editing and saving. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only one specific record meets criteria but doesnt queue workflow actions ? Have you confirmed this is the case if you replicate the record create-save-edit-save ? If you can reliably replicate the issue this way then the answer likely lies in whats different from that record to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Are you quite certain that the workflow is active? You can verify this by forcing it to also do a trivial field update, and validate that your workflow is in fact firing ...

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is firing the debug log shows that it is evaluating the workflow criteria and that it passed the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Consider security settings on sobject: Are you viewing debug log as admin user, and then looking at queue after a non sys-admin user attempted to update record to fire workflow ? If users cant edit or set fields used to fire workflow rules and the associated actions then results may differ to what you are seeing as an admin. Try looking at debug log from end user perspective if havent already.

Comment: I am running all edit/saves and viewing debug logs as administrator. I am not running anything as an end user yet until I can verify that this is working correctly. There are records being applied to this workflow, I just cannot seem to get a particular record to be put under it - when I see in the debug logs that the criteria was met